# SessionFactory not getting autowired in spring boot 1.5.2 with hibernate 5

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot

I have followed quite a few answers here on StackOverflow but I'm still stuck on this issue.
I'm adding Spring Boot Data JPA to a legacy primefaces project.
I have setup the Configuration as explained in many threads here. When I debug it I can see that the entityManagerFactory is correctly injected and that the unwrap method correctly returns a valid session factory.
However, on this other class where I'm autowiring the session factory, the session factory is null, it's not getting injected. I double checked the code and it's not setting this value anywhere else. Can you guys spot what could be going on? thanks in advance,

Here's the relevant code:

BeanConfiguration:

```
@Configuration
public class BeanConfiguration {

@Autowired
private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

@Bean
public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = entityManagerFactory.unwrap(SessionFactory.class);
    if (sessionFactory == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("factory is not a hibernate factory");
   }
    return sessionFactory;
}
}
```

Spring Application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean() {
        FacesServlet servlet = new FacesServlet();
        return new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "*.xhtml");
    }
}
```

The class where I want to inject it:

```
@Service
public class HibernateUtil<T, Type extends Serializable> implements IHibernateGenericoDAO<T, Serializable> {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end I was able to solve it using a slightly different strategy.
Instead of injecting the session factory, I injected the entitymanager:

`@PersistenceContext
protected EntityManager em;`

And then used it in the methods to create a criteria:
`Criteria cq = em.unwrap(Session.class).createCriteria(MyEntity.class);`